# Validating checkboxes with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to amend my script so if *ANY* of the 2 checkboxes are selected, it says '*Woo hoo!*'. Where am I going wrong?

**HTML:**

```
0:<input type="checkbox" name="remove_0" id="remove_0">
<br>
1:<input type="checkbox" name="remove_1" id="remove_1">
<br><br>
<button id="submitTCP">
Hit me!
</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#submitTCP").click(function(event){

  event.preventDefault();

  if ($('input:checkbox', this).is(':checked')) {
    alert('Woo hoo!');
  } else {
      alert('Please select something!');
      return false;
  }

})
```

**JSFiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/6qh0c8fm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `this` is parent submit button not checkbox

```js
$("#submitTCP").click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    if ($('input:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
        alert('checkboxes checked');
    } else {
        alert('Please select something!');
        return false;
    }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
0:<input type="checkbox" name="remove_0" id="remove_0">
<br>
1:<input type="checkbox" name="remove_1" id="remove_1">
<br><br>
<button id="submitTCP">
    Hit me!
</button>
```

Comment: D'oh. Thank you so much, Krishna :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no peramanent function to check either checkbox is checked but it can be done using click and getting it's `checked` property.

```js
 $('#cb').click(function () {
        if (this.checked == true) {
            console.log('checked');
        }
        else {
            console.log('un-checked');
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb"/>
```